# Try to check the inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery

I tried write a code that get value from inputs and check the value 
the function start on button click and some how it doesn`t work 
and return nothing to the #res div

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("button#RegisterB").click(function(){
        var UserName=$('#username').value();
        var PassWord=$('#password').value();
        var RPassWord=$('#repassword').value();
        var Email=$('#email').value();
        var phonenum=$('#phonenum').value()+$('#select').value();
        if((UserName=="")&&(PassWord=="")&&(RPassWord=="")&&(Email=="")&&(phonenum==""))
            $('#res').html("fill all");
        else { 
            if(PassWord!=RPassWord)
                $('#res').html("not match");
            if($.isNumeric(phone)==flase&&phonenum.length()!=10)
                $('#res').html("phone worng");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add your `HTML` code too, and try to explain a little better what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: any errors showing in the console?

Comment: Is `#select` an `select` element with options? Also, there is not `value()` in `jQuery`, it's only `val()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying to valuate the users input.
Instead of a complicated if-else-if-else-elseif, I recommend to valuate the fields individual.

```
$(function(){
  $("button#RegisterB").click(function(){
    var error = '';

    if( $('#username').val().length == 0 ) { error += 'Fill in the username please<br />'; }
    if( $('#PassWord').val().length == 0 ) { error += 'Fill in the password please<br />'; }
    if( $('#RPassWord').val().length == 0 ) { error += 'Fill in the re-password please<br />'; }
    if( $('#PassWord').val() != $('#RPassWord').val() ) { error += 'The passwords do not match<br />'; }
    var phonenum=$('#phonenum').val()+$('#select').val();
    if( phonenum.length == 0 ) { error += 'Fill in the phonenumber please<br />'; }
    else if ( $.isNumeric(phone) == false or phonenum.length != 10 ) { error += 'The phonenumber is invalid<br />'; }

    if( error != '' ) {
        $('#res').html( error );
    }
    else {
        // everything okay!
    }

  });
});
```

Please note that you have some errors in your code.

`.length()` isn't a function, it should be `.length`
`$.isNumeric(phone)==flase`, typo `flase` should be `false`

Comment: @Twebs, if the answer suits you, please mark it as answer by using the v mark on the left

Answer (score 0):

Is `#select` an `select` element with options? Also, there is not `value()` in `jQuery`, it's only `val()`. You define `phonenum` in your code but you use `phone` when you do `$.isNumeric(phone)`, and `flase != false` and finally, hope I didn't missed anything else, `phonenum.length()` should be `phonenum.length`, because `.length` is a property of an object, not a method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button#RegisterB").click(function() {
    var UserName = $('#username').val();
    var PassWord = $('#password').val();
    var RPassWord = $('#repassword').val();
    var Email = $('#email').val();
    var phonenum = $('#phonenum').val() + $('#select :selected').val();
    if ((UserName == "") && (PassWord == "") && (RPassWord == "") && (Email == "") && (phonenum == ""))
      $('#res').html("fill all");
    else {
      if (PassWord != RPassWord)
        $('#res').html("not match");
      if ($.isNumeric(phonenum) == false && phonenum.length != 10)
        $('#res').html("phone wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input, select{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type='text' id='username' name='username' placeholder='username'>
<input type='password' id='password' name='password' placeholder='password'>
<input type='password' id='repassword' name='repassword' placeholder='repassword'>
<input type='text' id='email' name='email' placeholder='email'>
<input type='text' id='phonenum' name='phonenum' placeholder='phonenum'>
<select id='select'>
  <option value='a'>a</option>
  <option value='b'>b</option>
  <option value='c'>c</option>
</select>
<button id='RegisterB' type='button'>Button</button>
</form>
<p id='res'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let's see bugs in your code:

- `value()` is not a `jQuery` function, use `val()` instead.
- `var phonenum=$('#phonenum').value()+$('#select').value();`, variable `phonenum` will be `undefined` if you input nothing, which will cause the first `if` test always be `false`
- Variable `phone` in your code `if($.isNumeric(phone)==flase&&phonenum.length()!=10)` is undefined, I guess it's supposed to be `phonenum`
- Also your typo `flase` in the above line of code, it's `false`
- Again in this line of code, `length` is not a function of `string`, it's an attribute, you need to refer it as `phonenum.length`

If you open your browser console and run your code again, you can reproduce it.

I added some `HTML` snippet to test the fixed `js`, you can change it according your requirement:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("button#RegisterB").click(function(){
    var UserName=$('#username').val();
    var PassWord=$('#password').val();
    var RPassWord=$('#repassword').val();
    var Email=$('#email').val();
    var phonenum=$('#phonenum').val()+$('#select').val();
    console.log("phonenum is undefined here!!!")
    console.log(phonenum)
    if((UserName=="")&&(PassWord=="")&&(RPassWord=="")&&(Email=="")&&(phonenum=="")) {
    
        $('#res').html("fill all");}
    else { if(PassWord!=RPassWord)
            $('#res').html("not match");
            
            if($.isNumeric(phonenum) == false &&phonenum.length!=10)
                $('#res').html("phone worng");
        }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 Username: <input type="text" id="username" ><br>
 Password: <input type="password" id="password" ><br>
 Re password: <input type="repassword" id="password" ><br>
 Email: <input type="text" id="email" ><br>
 Phone Num: <input type="text" id="phonenum" ><br>
 Select: <input type="text" id="phonenum" ><br>
 <button id="RegisterB">click me</button><br>
 <span id="res">Res info<span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button#RegisterB").click(function() {
    var UserName = $('#username').val();
    var PassWord = $('#password').val();
    var RPassWord = $('#repassword').val();
    var Email = $('#email').val();
    var phonenum = $('#phonenum').val();
    //alert(phonenum);
    var select  =$('#select').val();
    if ((UserName == "") || (PassWord == "") || (RPassWord == "") || (Email == "") || (phonenum == ""))
      $('#res').html("fill all");
    else if (PassWord != RPassWord)
    $('#res').html("not match");
    else if ($.isNumeric(phonenum) == false || phonenum.length != 10)
        $('#res').html("phone wrong");
      else
        $('#res').html("");
  });
});
```

```css
input, select{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type='text' id='username' name='username' placeholder='username'>
<input type='password' id='password' name='password' placeholder='password'>
<input type='password' id='repassword' name='repassword' placeholder='repassword'>
<input type='text' id='email' name='email' placeholder='email'>
<input type='text' id='phonenum' name='phonenum' placeholder='phonenum'>
<select id='select'>
  <option value='a'>a</option>
  <option value='b'>b</option>
  <option value='c'>c</option>
</select>
<button id='RegisterB' type='button'>Button</button>
</form>
<p id='res'></p>
```